# How to extract EPG data from a rec/ts file?

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv

I need to extract the data stream of a rec/ts file.
What I've tried until now is with `avconv`

```
avconv -i filename.rec
```

I get this output

```
avconv version 0.8.17-6:0.8.17-1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 15 2015 17:00:31 with gcc 4.7.2
  ...
Input #0, mpegts, from 'filename.rec':
  Duration: 01:54:55.94, start: 74083.801633, bitrate: 400 kb/s
  ...
  Program 28479
    Metadata:
    ...
    Stream #0.0[0x475](ger): Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 320 kb/s
    Stream #0.1[0x81a]: Data: [5][0][0][0] / 0x0005
    Stream #0.2[0x881]: Data: [11][0][0][0] / 0x000B
    ...
```

AFIK the data stream contains the EPG information. Does it?

The following command

```
avconv -i filename.rec -f ffmetadata metadata.txt
```

outputs this to metadata.txt

```
;FFMETADATA1
```

and with

```
avconv -i filename.rec -map 0:1 -f ffmetadata metadata.txt
```

I get the message `Data stream encoding not supported yet (only streamcopy)`

The file `filename.rec`has following content which I would like to extract:

[image]

Comment: you're just trying to extract EPG?

Comment: @rogerdpack: yes I guess it is EPG Data. The file has been recorded in a Topfield PVR. I wold like to extract this data from a command line or a script.

Comment: I don't think FFmpeg can.  If you have access to the .ts file then http://superuser.com/questions/1027014/how-to-l-extract-epg-data-from-mpeg-ts-files might be helpful